# How to get my divs in line? And how to group picture and button in one link?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I posted this question earlier when I was more a novice but now that im back with more knowledge I'm still running into problems. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/eyxmbsvp/3/

1) The button is not acting as a link even though its nested in the  tag. 
2) I have my item classes floating left but they are still stacked on top of each other.

help please!

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">   
    <div class="item">    
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/maxxchewning">
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/HrkZQ3EOmFQ/hqdefault.jpg"/>
                <div class="button"/>
    </a>    
        </div>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Christianguzmanfitne">
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/zsD_7hkfEwY/hqdefault.jpg"/>
            <div class="button"/>
        </a>         
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PhysiquesOfGreatness">
            <img src="http://v017o.popscreen.com/VzFBeVBjMHhpRWMx_o_new-physiques-of-greatness-intro-25.jpg"/>
            <div class="button"/>
        </a>     
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap { 
margin:auto;
width: 1000px;
}

.item {
    float:left;
}

.item img {
    width:33%;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.button {
    background-color:green;
    height:50px;
    width:33%;   
}
.button:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the page in the browser, right-clicking and then choosing "inspect element"? That will help you understand why your floats are not working.

Comment: This `<div class="button"/>` is invalid `div` tags are not allowed to self-close ...

Comment: You can also use the `<input>` tag for your button instead of making a div

Comment: Those `<img>`s need alt text.

Answer (score 2):

First, always close `<div>` tags. Replace `<div />` to `<div></div>`. Even if the tag has no content inside.

Then, move width 33% to `.item` class and remove them from `.item img` and `.button`.

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n8j6oq79/

HTML buttons:

`<div class="button"></div>`

and CSS:

```
.wrap { 
    margin:auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    width:33.333%;
}

.item img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.button {
    background-color:green;
    height:50px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

.

### Spacing between the items

If you want nice spacing between the items, you can play with margin of `.item` elements:

```
.item {
    float:left;

    width:32%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ydz0dnun/

Don't forget that every size is x3 (because you have 3 items per row).

This particular combination 32% and 1% creates 4 equal spaces (before each item and one after the last item). The last space is because we omit 0.33333% and that adds up to additional 1%.

Answer (score 0):

the issue of your links not working and boxes not floating is because your `div`s look like this:

```
<div class="button"/>
```

`div`s are not self-closing tags, you need to close them properly

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

You should also be adding `width: 33%` to `.item` not the `img` since it's the parent. Then set the width of `img` and `a` how you would like (I set it to `30%` with a `margin: 0 1%` for some additional spacing):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyxmbsvp/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div>`, for a button, you should use the following tag:

`<input type="button" onClick=SomeAction() />`

In your html file, you can include a small javascript code that will define the function "SomeAction()"
that will be a single line which allows you to go to your required link:

```
<script>
function SomeAction()
{
open("yourLink");
}
</script>
```

If you want a button then this will give you the required functionality of a button, otherwise if you prefer using divs that's okay too however do pay attention to the opening and closing tags.